# Asking interviewer preliminary feedback if other companies are pushing

Tags: job-offer

I am waiting for a decision that should come within Friday and I would like to give precedence to this company.

However, another two companies are pushing with formal agreements and contracts.

Do you think it is ok if I ask the interviewer about what they think to do? Mind, the ‘deadline’ for the decision is Friday, if I asked, I would ask this evening (Wednesday) or tomorrow (Thursday). So it just a matter of one or two days.

I hate being pushy but the other companies have been pushing too for a while! There is a concrete chance that they will complain (at least one company, which is the second best offer after this pending one).

Comment: With the second best company, I cannot predict! Otherwise I would never do this.

Comment: You don’t want to push things, but it also doesn’t hurt to let your preferred company know that you have offers on the table.

Comment: @Kaz what do you suggest then? To write something politely?

Answer (score 5):

> I am waiting for a decision that should come within Friday and I would like to give precedence to this company.

Congratulations  ;)

> However, other two companies are pushing with formal agreements and contracts.

Even better since you seem to have multiple options, **but don't let them push you over a couple of days**. You could tell them you need two, three days to make a decision.

> Do you think is is ok if I ask the interviewer about what they think to do? Mind, the ‘deadline’ for the decision is friday, if I asked, I would ask this evening (Wednesday) or tomorrow (Thursday). So it just a matter of one or two days.

**No, don't push your preferred company over a couple of days either** (Especially since you share a mutual feeling about *'being pushed'*). That won't leave a good impression in various ways. Their internal processes might just take until Friday, and waiting a few more days is bearable on your side.

> I hate being pushing but the other companies have been pushing too for a while! There is a concrete chance that they will complain (at least one company, which is the second best offer after this pending one).

Take into consideration that a hasty decision over an employment might not be the best appraoch in terms of the outcome for both sides. If the other two companies complain over a couple of days for you to make up your mind, they might not be a good choice anyway..

In regards to the two companies that want to push you to make a decision: You could write a formal e-mail thanking them for their interest and firmly state that you will make a decision by Monday in the morning for example.

That way they know when to expect your decision and hopefully realize that therer's no need to push you anymore until that specific date.

If they still continue then it's a red flag. Either they are really desperate or they don't respect your need for a couple of days until you make up your mind. Neither leave a good impression on the employees side..

Comment: Thank you, this was valuable!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine.

As a hiring manager, if I know a candidate is weighing other offers, it helps me justify prioritizing pushing them more quickly through our own pipeline, or telling them "OK good luck!" if we're not on a path to an offer but are dinking around.

It also gives an opportunity for me to tell you a realistic timeframe - "I'm not going to be able to tell you yes or no for two weeks for sure, so do what you have to do" may be an outcome - not optimal but then at least you're not spending effort and goodwill trying to put off the other offers by 2-3 days when it's not going to help anyway.